# Can a variable be made readonly in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to prevent a variable from being changed. Specifically a property of an Object:

```
var foo = { bar: 'baz' };

// do something to foo to make it readonly

foo.bar = 'boing'; // should throw exception
```

Can this be done?

Comment: Try to use javascript Object.defineProperty, read this it may be useful https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try

```
Object.defineProperty(foo, "bar", { writable: false });
```

and the later assignment either fails silently or, if you are in strict mode, throws an exception (according to David Flanagan's "JavaScript : The Definitive Guide" ).

Comment: you can omit **writable: false** // it's by default false

Comment: Note: `writable` is false by default, according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty).

Comment: `writable` is indeed false by default. Some redundancy to make it more obvious doesn't hurt though.

Comment: actually this default applies only when you *create* the property ; here however, `bar` already exists and has `writable` implicitly set to `true`. On the MDN page, I find the general explanations not very clear on that, but further down the page, in "Adding properties and default values", you have an example that shows much better the differences between creating and modifying a property.

Answer (score 3):

Use a function:

```
var foo = function() {
  var bar = 'baz';

  return {
    getBar: function() {
      return bar;
    }
  }
}();
```

In that way foo.bar is undefined, you can only access it through foo.getBar();

Comment: Although your answer is correct, but it's not the same thing as the original question. You are suggesting only a technique to achieve the same goal...

Answer (score 0):

Look at this example:

```
var Foo = function(){
     this.var1 = "A";   // public
     var var2 = "B";    // private
     this.getVar2 = function(){ return var2; }
}

var foo = new Foo();

console.log(foo.var1);   // will output A
console.log(foo.var2)    // undefined
console.log(foo.getVar2())    // will output B
```

Comment: I believe they want a static variable which can be accessed externally, but not changed.

Comment: It's simply wrap that variable and just provide a getter and not a setter